# C: Can i know the restore option in pubnub subscribe using C SDK

Tags: c, publish-subscribe, pubnub

I am using a pubnub in my project for signalling purpose. i am using C sdk for programming. 
i am facing an issue that if two users are communicating each other if the internet is disconnected at user 1 side, and the user 2 send the request on their subscribed channel, after user 1 connected to internet,user 1 is getting all the requests which are sent by another user 2.

The solution for this,  is in http://www.pubnub.com/docs/javascript/api/reference.html#_arguments_11 , which is in Javascript, here it is using "restore: false" option in subscribe.

Can anyone suggest me the above solution in C sdk so that i can ignore the request sent from the user 2 when user 1 is disconnected from the internet and connected back to internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting resume_on_reconnect to false on the C side should prevent this behavior. If that doesn't work for you, and you're still having issues with this, shoot us an email at support@pubnub.com and we're take care of you from there!

geremy

Comment: i have added resume_on_reconnect(p, "false") in my code, and im facing another issue that in my linux pc for testing purpose im disabling the network and connecting it back, when i do this and after if i publish the msg on subscribed channel, it is not responding (i mean not getting anything). im not getting the message which i published.

Comment: Please contact us at support@pubnub.com so we can get more information on your implementation.

Comment: Hi sir, i have contacted u and i got the solution , added these lines
 

    pubnub_subscribe(p,"sub_channel", 20, NULL, NULL);
        pubnub_error_policy(p, ~(1<<PNR_TIMEOUT), true);
        if (pubnub_sync_last_result(sync) == PNR_TIMEOUT) {
            pubnub_reset_subscribe(p, true);
            continue;
        }

Thanks for ur support